# button in the list as link

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want the website to open the link after pressing the button, and not like it is now that I have to press the icon to open the link. I have to click on the small icon for the link to open and I want to make this link open as if you press the button
and if someone would like it, here are nice transitions, maybe someone will be useful

```css
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 3rem;
}

nav li::before,
nav li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav li::before {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

nav li::after {
  background-color: #66CCFF;
  transform: translate(1.5rem, 1.5rem);
  z-index: -2;
}

nav li:hover {
  transform: translate(1.5rem, 1.5rem);
  color: white;
}

nav li:hover::before {
  background-color: #66CCFF;
}

nav li:hover::after {
  background-color: white;
  transform: translate(-1.5rem, -1.5rem);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="social">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to get. Give more explanation, pls.

Comment: in this form, the link will open only when you click on the icon, e.g. facebook.  I want the link to open as the user presses the button, not as the user presses the icon

Comment: There are no buttons or forms in the code you've posted

Comment: there is none but this list creates a kind of button. I know it's not a button, but it looks like a button

Comment: I made your code snippets previewable within SO (adding FA v4.7.0). Hopefully now the problem is clearer to potential responders - as I understand, the problem is that the link's size is smaller than the `<li>` (which is styled like a button), so clicking outside the link (but within the `<li>`) doesn't do anything.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/KubaPilat/f43r5w7m/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a button and do this, and if its not what u want then please explain your question

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="social">
           <ul>
             <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"><button type="button" name="button">Fb</button></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"><button type="button" name="button">Fb</button></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"><button type="button" name="button">Fb</button></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github"><button type="button" name="button">Fb</button></i></a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I already know. I thought you can't give a href out of the list, but you can

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><li><i class="fa fa-github"></i></li></a>
```

Comment: It is bad HTML though, having an anchor as the direct child of a `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this style. This basically expands your anchor to occupy the full `<li>` size.

```
nav li a {
   height: 100%;
   display: block;
}
```

Full previewable code:

```css
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 3rem;
}

nav li::before,
nav li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav li::before {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

nav li::after {
  background-color: #66CCFF;
  transform: translate(1.5rem, 1.5rem);
  z-index: -2;
}

nav li:hover {
  transform: translate(1.5rem, 1.5rem);
  color: white;
}

nav li:hover::before {
  background-color: #66CCFF;
}

nav li:hover::after {
  background-color: white;
  transform: translate(-1.5rem, -1.5rem);
}

nav li a {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="social">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```